# Unstable connection

Tags: networking, internet, connection

last weeks I noticed that my connection is so unstable. I get all the time connection timeout on pages, I ping google.com and ping 8.8.8.8 and i get request timeout but after 4-5 minutes working again and then again request timeout.

Games not loading, they load for 1 minute and then dont load again.

Tried to restart my router/pc lot of times, clean ethernet cables from dust, change cables, router is not hot.

Edit: Tried what @john suggested: `(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt (2) ipconfig /flushdns (3) restart the computer and Test` didnt fix the problem.

Do you guys have any clue what is going on? its crazy problem!

Comment: Basic TCP/IP Reset
 
Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer
and Test

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I tried this but still nothing! :(

Comment: Try DISM / SFC    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Wait, what the above commands will do ?

Comment: They are initial Windows repairs.  Repairs get more aggressive as you proceed.

Comment: No indication if the problem is local to the pc or remote. You need to run some traceroutes on ip addresses with and without rDNS resolution during working and not working phases.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click CMD > Run as administrator

Run each command in this order:

•   Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

•   Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

```
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

•   Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

•   Flush DNS resolver cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

•   Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

•   Flush routing table (reboot required):

```
route /f
```

Now shut down your machine and unplug the power from your router for 30 seconds. Also remove the power from any inter-connecting devices like netgear switches or powerline adapters. Fire everything back up except your computer.

For your computer, unplug the power cable from the back and hold down the power button at the front (if laptop you will need to remove the battery if you can). This will flush any residual power from the system. Now finally, return the power cable to the computer and switch it on + test.

Comment: Tried, nothing. :(